# ${NSD_GetText} returns a Empty.string - I've got stuck

Tags: installation, nsis, gettext, nsdialogs

I'm trying to crate an installation with a custom form for settings:

configform.nsdInc:

```
; =========================================================
; This file was generated by NSISDialogDesigner 1.4.2.0
; http://coolsoft.altervista.org/nsisdialogdesigner
;
; Do not edit it manually, use NSISDialogDesigner instead!
; =========================================================

; handle variables
Var hCtl_configForm
Var hCtl_configForm_imgQuality
Var hCtl_configForm_wpctrlPort
Var hCtl_configForm_wpctrlIp
Var hCtl_configForm_atmCmdPort
Var hCtl_configForm_atmCmdIp
Var hCtl_configForm_Label3
Var hCtl_configForm_Label2
Var hCtl_configForm_Label1    

Var T0
Var T1
Var T2
Var T3
Var T4    

!include nsDialogs.nsh

; dialog create function
Function fnc_configForm_Create

  ; === configForm (type: Dialog) ===
  nsDialogs::Create 1018
  Pop $hCtl_configForm
  ${If} $hCtl_configForm == error
    Abort
  ${EndIf}
  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Dialog title..." "Dialog subtitle..."

  ; === imgQuality (type: ComboBox) ===
  ${NSD_CreateComboBox} 77.67u 43.69u 63.85u 12.92u ""
  Pop $hCtl_configForm_imgQuality
  ${NSD_CB_AddString} $hCtl_configForm_imgQuality "15"
  ....
  ${NSD_CB_AddString} $hCtl_configForm_imgQuality "97"

  ; === wpctrlPort (type: Text) ===
  ${NSD_CreateText} 235.65u 24u 57.92u 12.31u ""
  Pop $hCtl_configForm_wpctrlPort 

  ; === wpctrlIp (type: Text) ===
  ${NSD_CreateText} 77.67u 24u 154.03u 12.31u ""
  Pop $hCtl_configForm_wpctrlIp

  ; === atmCmdPort (type: Text) ===
  ${NSD_CreateText} 235.65u 3.69u 57.92u 12.31u ""
  Pop $hCtl_configForm_atmCmdPort 

  ; === atmCmdIp (type: Text) ===
  ${NSD_CreateText} 77.67u 3.69u 154.03u 12.31u ""
  Pop $hCtl_configForm_atmCmdIp


  ; === Label3 (type: Label) ===
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 7.9u 44.92u 65.82u 11.69u "Image quality:"
  Pop $hCtl_configForm_Label3

  ; === Label2 (type: Label) ===
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 7.9u 25.85u 65.82u 11.69u "WPCTRL IP\Port:"
  Pop $hCtl_configForm_Label2

  ; === Label1 (type: Label) ===
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 7.9u 5.54u 65.82u 11.69u "ATMCMD IP\Port:"
  Pop $hCtl_configForm_Label1

FunctionEnd

; dialog show function
Function fnc_configForm_Show
  Call fnc_configForm_Create
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function fnc_save_config
    ${NSD_GetText} hCtl_configForm_atmCmdIp $T0
    ${NSD_GetText} hCtl_configForm_atmCmdPort $T1
    ${NSD_GetText} hCtl_configForm_wpctrlIp $T2
    ${NSD_GetText} hCtl_configForm_wpctrlPort $T3
    ${NSD_GetText} hCtl_configForm_imgQuality $T4

    FileOpen $5 "$INSTDIR\M3Remote.xml" w
    FileWrite $5 "<Settings><Login>Remote</Login> <Communications><WP><Ip>"
    FileWrite $5 $T2
    FileWrite $5 "</Ip><Port>"
    FileWrite $5 $T3
    FileWrite $5 "</Port>"
```

......
        FileWrite $5 "ru-RU"
        FileClose $5
    FunctionEnd

A main .nsi script:

```
; Script generated by the HM NIS Edit Script Wizard.

SetCompressor /SOLID LZMA

; HM NIS Edit Wizard helper defines
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MMMFFF"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION 1.0
!define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "AAAA"
!define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "http://e.com"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\M3Remote"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"
!define PRODUCT_DISTRIBUTION_FILE "MMMFFF_setup_${PRODUCT_VERSION}.exe"

RequestExecutionLevel admin

!define TARGETDIR "install"
!addplugindir "${TARGETDIR}"

; MUI 1.67 compatible
!include "MUI.nsh"

!include nsDialogs.nsh

; MUI Settings
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING

; Welcome page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "C:\Program Files\Lanit\M3Remote"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES


!include "configForm.nsdinc"
Page custom fnc_configForm_Show fnc_save_config

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

; Language files
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Russian"

; MUI end
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include NsisXml.nsh

Name "M3Remote ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"               ; название кнопки инсталлятора на панели задач
Caption "Установка M3Remote ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"  ; заголовок окна инсталлятора
OutFile "M3Remote_setup_${PRODUCT_VERSION}.exe"  ; имя файла инсталлятора
InstallDir "C:\Program Files\Lanit\M3Remote"

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Section Filecopy
  CreateDirectory $INSTDIR
  CreateDirectory $INSTDIR\Logs
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"

  SetOutPath $INSTDIR

  File /r binary\*
```

.........
 SectionEnd

```
Function un.onUninstSuccess
.....
FunctionEnd

Function un.onInit
....
FunctionEnd

Section uninstall
 ...............
SectionEnd
```

The problem is, that I'm completely can't get out what's the problem with
    ${NSD_GetText}
, because it aways returns an empty string. 
And I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing in a valid Window handle to `${NSD_GetText}` because you forgot the `$` prefix on the variable names. Change `${NSD_GetText} hCtl_configForm_atmCmdIp $T0` to `${NSD_GetText} $hCtl_configForm_atmCmdIp $T0` etc.